# What is the maximum buffer size that can be passed from user space to kernel space using libnl?

Tags: c, kernel, netlink

In my homework I came to know that we can send a buffer of size 4096(kernel page size) between user space and kernel space.

**How can we send more sized buffer?**

I think fragmentation is a way to increase the buffer size. **Is there any other method?**